# Multiple conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Table I am working with]

This is the Table I am working with

I need to access the data points with 'Duration'>70 and 'End Terminal'==10
Hence I tried

```
kj[kj['Duration']>70] 
kj[kj['End Terminal'] == 10]
```

above commands are working fine separately but when I club them as:

```
kj[kj['End Terminal'] == 10] & kj[kj['Duration']>70]
```

there is an error, hence how to use both conditions in one statement in Pandas-Python

Comment: Put separate conditions in brackets kj[ (cond1) & (cond2) ]

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick:

```
kj[(kj['End Terminal'] == 10) & (kj['Duration']>70)]
```

Comment: I removed the typo,and this worked  :                                                   kj[(kj['End Terminal'] == 10) & (kj['Duration']>70)]